# Change default BOOT_COMPLETED Activity on Samsung Galaxy Camera

Tags: android, android-intent

My question specifically concerns the Samsung Galaxy Camera devices. It ships with a customized camera application. I guess Samsung developed their own. Since this device can be seen as a camera instead of a phone with a camera they seem to decided that their camera app should start on boot, in contrast to other devices which take the user to the home screen after boot completes.

Now, in our szenario we ship the device with our own application that has its own camera interface. We could run our application in kiosk mode but we want to allow the user to use other apps that might be helpful for his daily work as well.

So ideally, the device should start the home screen after boot completes. The user could  then decide to start our app or another app. But if this isn’t possible it would also be ok if our app would start on boot instead of the home screen (since the user would reach the home screen with the home button)

Since I don’t see any chance to force the home screen to appear after boot completes, I tried to start our own application by default. To implement that I created a receiver with the following filter:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

When the intent is received, I start the main Activity of our application.

In the result, after booting the device, Samsungs default camera app will start first. You’ll see their main Activity and the most annoying part: the camera lens will be fully extended. A split second after this our app starts automatically.

My guess is, that Samsungs camera app also reacts to the boot-completed-event. Is there any chance that we could prevent their app from being started?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be achieved - albeit in a convoluted manor - without rooting using DevicePolicyManager. By making your app a device administrator and disabling the camera the built in camera app won't launch on power up (nor camera button press). Once your app has launched re-enable the camera and have fun.

I haven't had a chance to create the code (and will update this answer when I have), but I have tested to an extent using the DisableCameraDevice app from the play store. With this app setup the camera app doesn't launch at startup and my app which receives BOOT_COMPLETE launches after a few seconds of homescreen time.

It also doesn't stop the camera button events (but does stop the camera app) so you can do the same for this (which also seems to ignore android:priority values).

If you wanted to go further you could even make you're camera app respond to the ACTION_MAIN, CATEGORY_HOME intents mentioned by CommonsWare and persistently select it as the homescreen app.

Combined with a full screen app which doesn't display the home/back buttons you're locked down pretty well for a fool proof camera to give customers.

Comment: I installed DisableCameraDevice from Google Play and also installed Tasker and this seems to work.  I created Tasks to send Intents to DisableCameraDevice to disable the camera on Device Shutdown and Display State Off. Then I enable the camera on Device Boot and exit of Display State Off.  There is a bit of a delay when booting because Tasker doesn't start very fast. And if you do a "Power off" it bypasses the Tasker Device Shutdown event. (Which I noticed means that Tasker loses information, as well, so I doubt it is Android compliant.)

Answer (score 0):

The camera app uses the BOOT_COMPLETED permission attached to a receiver. It is a system application, so you would need root to modify it on the system level. If you are packing your own firmware, this would not be an issue. The standard launcher does not have the standard boot permissions, but your app would. This would avoid the issue of not booting to anything by simply removing the permission. Also, a priority of 499 is better to fall within the limit of 500.